# Ignored Espresso test cases not shown in HTML Test Report

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-testing

When running Espresso test cases with gradle and check the HTML test report I can only see PASS and FAIL test cases but not IGNORED ones.
Doing some troubleshooting, I force it to have an IGNORED test case using Assume, and a PASS one:

```
@Test
public void test_1() {
    Assume.assumeTrue("No WiFi connection. Set test to Ignored",false);
}

@Test
public void test_2() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

The output I get running gradlew app:connectedDebugAndroidTest with --info flag is:

> Starting 2 tests on emulator25(AVD) - 7.1.1
>
> com.myapp.androidTest > test_1[emulator25(AVD) - 7.1.1] SKIPPED 
>           org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: No WiFi connection. Set test to Ignored
>           at org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(Assume.java:59)
>
> com.myapp.androidTest > test_1[emulator25(AVD) - 7.1.1] SUCCESS
>
> com.myapp.androidTest > test_2[emulator25(AVD) - 7.1.1] SUCCESS

So apparently test_1 is chaged from SKIPPED to SUCCESS for some reason, and therefore in the HTML test report test_1 and test_2 are shown as PASSED

[HTML AndroidTest report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozKRJ.jpg)

However, looking at XML test result the ignored test is there:

`<testsuite name="com.myapp.androidTest" tests="2" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" time="5.055" timestamp="2018-08-23T14:30:50" hostname="localhost"> <properties> <property name="device" value="emulator25(AVD) - 7.1.1"/> <property name="flavor" value="GLOBAL"/>` `<property name="project" value="app"/> </properties> <testcase name="test_1" classname="com.myapp.androidTest" time="2.99"> <skipped> org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: No WiFi connection. Set test to Ignored at org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(Assume.java:59) at com.myapp.androidTest.test_1(Iqiyi_DefaultSettings_VideoEvents_WIFI.java:124) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at` `org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80) at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61) at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527) at android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:129) at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56) at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384) at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)` `</skipped> </testcase> <testcase name="test_2" classname="com.myapp.androidTest" time="1.105"/> </testsuite>`

Any idea what is going on?

Using Gradle 4.4.1

PS. For Unit test there is no problem, and ignored tests are shown

[HTML UnitTest report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WcGA.jpg)